# Why click event calling blur event on sucess

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, click, blur

I wanted to populate a dropdownlist dynamically. So I have add event as follows in my .js file.

```
jQuery('#viewCriteriaTemplateDropdown').click(jQuery.proxy(this.PopulateTemplateDropdown, this));
jQuery('#viewCriteriaTemplateDropdown').change(jQuery.proxy(this.SelectTemplateDropdownBlur, this));
jQuery('#viewCriteriaTemplateDropdown').blur(jQuery.proxy(this.SelectTemplateDropdownBlur, this));
```

in PopulateTemplateDropDown I'm calling .net webservice as follows: If it is first time than only call this service otherwise donothing.

```
GetDisplayTemplates(
        si.ScreenTypeId, 
        si.ScreenContextId, 
        jQuery.proxy(this.PopulateTemplateDropdownSuccess, this),
        jQuery.proxy(this.PopulateTemplateDropdownFailure, this));
```

This web service returns list which I added into dropdownlist option in success function. To display only part of code I used following code in my success function.

```
var dropDown = $('viewCriteriaTemplateDropdown');
```

Now, code for populate dropdownlist and then:

```
dropDown.style.height = 'auto';
dropDown.size = (dictCount > 10 ? 10 : dictCount);
dropDown.selectedIndex = -1;
dropDown.focus();
```

here dictCount is no. of element in list.

After this I'm writing single function for both change and blur which reduced size of dropList to 1.

Now my problem is when I first click on list It is calling success function on completion of that control goes to blur event. I don't understand why It is happening. Because of going into blur list size reduced to 1. But in next click It is not calling blur function as it is second time and don't goes into success part.

Comment: `var dropDown = $('viewCriteriaTemplateDropdown');` must be `var dropDown = $('#viewCriteriaTemplateDropdown');`

Comment: try that way also still the same.

Comment: Try to post the html.

Comment: <select onfocus="Javascript:this.className='';"  id="viewCriteriaTemplateDropdown" class="" size="1" style="">

Comment: By html I mean the whole html wrapping the element with id viewCriteriaTemplateDropdown. Your problem seems jquery event delegation issue ( use event delegation if necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved by removing click event and populate dropdown in ready like this

```
var con = this;
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        con.PopulateTemplateDropdown();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `.focus()` on your element produces a blur event, even if your element already has focus.

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2uh9uosz/), and click the button several times.

Try to remove this maybe : `dropDown.focus();`